# SQL Queries "00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

Hi I have the following code

```
SELECT  entertainer_id,
        entertainer_groupname
FROM    casestudy_entertainer
INNER JOIN casestudy_availability ON 
casestudy_entertainer.entertainer_id 
     = CASESTUDY_AVAILABILITY.AVAILABILITY_ENTERTAINERID
INNER JOIN casestudy_calendardates ON 
CASESTUDY_AVAILABILITY.AVAILIBILITY_CALENDARDATEID 
     =  casestudy_calendardates.calendar_Id
WHERE   entertainer_type = '&Entertainer_TYPE' 
AND     casestudy_calendardates.calendar_date = '&Event_date'
```

And I don't seem to be able to figure out what its not liking when I run this. 
It gives me the following error

> ORA-00904: "CASESTUDY_AVAILIBILITY"."AVAILIBILITY_CALENDARDATEID": invalid identifier
>   00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:
>   Error at Line: 7 Column: 4

I do have all the tables in place with all the correct rows. 
The only thing is I have no data as of yet, Could this possibly be the issue?

Comment: Wild guess: maybe you should try the lower case for the table/column identifiers?(like in `from`/`inner join` clauses)

Comment: @notulysses is correct.  `ON` clause must match the `JOIN` clause in terms of case, i.e., `INNER JOIN casestudy_calendardates ON casestudy_availability.availability_calendardateid = casestudy_calendardates.calendar_Id`, etc...

Comment: @JonathanSteward: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should try the lower case for the table/column identifiers(like in `from`/`inner join` clauses):

```
SELECT  entertainer_id,
        entertainer_groupname
FROM    casestudy_entertainer
INNER JOIN casestudy_availability ON casestudy_entertainer.entertainer_id = casestudy_availability.availability_entertainerid
INNER JOIN casestudy_calendardates ON casestudy_availability.availibility_calendardateid = casestudy_calendardates.calendar_id
WHERE entertainer_type = '&Entertainer_TYPE'
  AND casestudy_calendardates.calendar_date = '&Event_date'
```

Comment: Can we please get an explanation as to what exactly you are talking about and why exactly someone marked this down; yet it's accepted. I'm very confused what is going on here with this solution and whether or not it's valid.

Comment: @Mr.Tea : I was talking about identifiers like database and table names being case sensitive on some platforms. Thus, basing my assumptions on the error message, I advised to change upper case identifiers to lower case identifiers. And the downvote part might be caused by my vague or insufficient initial elaboration)

Comment: @KyleBridenstine By default Oracle ignores upper/lower cases. But the DB you work on just now could be set DIFFERENTLY. Apparently, the asker had just that problem, but it is not the only possible one - other answers here are OK, too, and could serve in your case.

Answer (score 1):

This Error is caused by a special character in one of the columns of the database table. DBA will be able to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have same tablenames in your tables while left joining.

Change tablename of one , it will work.

Answer (score 0):

no data is not the issue, you won't simply get a null result. ORA-00904 indicates, that you used a column that does not exist or does not comply to the Oracle specification.

Please check for correct naming. You might be better of with shorter names or at least table aliasses to get to code more readable.

Without knowing your table structure I cannot tell you where the error is. do a `describe table_name;`

It would also help to have the oracle version number `SELECT * FROM V$VERSION` or `SELECT version FROM V$INSTANCE`
 and your client software you are using

Answer (score 0):

What is interesting, Oracle gives that message not only if the name of the column is bad, but also if the name of the table/alias is bad - not defined alias, twice defined (as mentioned @PrajwalRai), error in the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but maybe it helps:

sometimes you copy and paste text from a source that has a different character set ...

Type it over in sql-dev for instance and see if the error is gone

Answer (score 0):

I was able to clear this error in an Oracle DB using Oracle SQL Developer by placing strings in single quotes instead of double quotes